# fsockopen() unable to connect to localhost : 25

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one project developed using codeigniter framework.In that I need to send mail to the user but I'm getting the error while sending mail

```
    <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

    <p>Severity: Warning</p>
    <p>Message:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to localhost:25 (Connection refused)</p>
    <p>Filename: libraries/Email.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 1689</p>
```

why I'm getting this?

Comment: Do you have SMTP server running on the localhost?

Comment: post the `email config` used.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run mail function on local you need to run SMTP server on 
else you can try it on live server